# How can I find what version of DisplayPort my graphics card supports?

Tags: displayport

DisplayPort comes in different versions, all of which use the same cable and terminator but different versions of the protocol. How can I find out what version of DisplayPort my graphics card and driver supports?

I am using an x230 (from `lspci -vv`)

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: Lenovo 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
        Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0
        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 29
        Region 0: Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
        Region 2: Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        Region 4: I/O ports at 6000 [size=64]
        [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: i915
        Kernel modules: i915
```

Comment: Any news on this?

Answer (score 3):

From https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000023781/graphics-drivers.html :

> For 2nd and 3rd Generation Intel® Core™ Processors the maximum supported resolutions are:
>
> - DisplayPort 1.1 = 2560x1600 at 60 Hz
> - HDMI 1.4 = 1920x1200 at 60 Hz
> - DVI (Single-link) = 1920x1200 at 60 Hz
> - VGA = 2048x1536 at 75 Hz

So, it looks like it's DisplayPort 1.1.

Comment: Is there anyway to get that data from the driver itself? I'm on DisplayPort right now at 3840x1080. So that spec is not right.

Comment: Not to my knowledge. `xrandr --prop` and `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`, the best sources of information from the driver as far as I know, don't seem to identify the DisplayPort standard version in use. You'll need to identify your exact CPU model, look up its specifications from intel.com website, then check what the exact iGPU type used in that particular processor model will be able to do.

Comment: @Evan the spec is right, but poorly formulated; the cap is on the bandwidth, not the resolution. 3840×1080 has nearly the same bandwidth requirements as 2560×1600, at the same refresh rate.